# Swift Tableview data load getting Index out of range

Tags: json, swift, tableview

My scenario, I am trying to load `JSON` data into `Tableview`. Here, `Tableview` custom `cell` I am maintaining. Whenever trying to upload data into `tableview`, I may have chance to add new data from `server`. 
Here, while loading I am getting `Index` out of range error. Every time I am calling `JSON` function from `viewWillAppear`. I have enough `data`, Inside my array nothing uneven data. Below `code` I am using

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated) // No need for semicolon

        self.tableArray.removeAll()
        self.cartname.removeAll()
        self.parentid.removeAll()
        self.name.removeAll()
        self.year.removeAll()

        parseJSON()
    }
```

This is my JSON Process

```
if let content = json["content"] as? [[String:String]] {
            print(json)
            for category in content {
                let cat_id = category["cat_id"]
                let cat_name =  category["cat_name"]
                let cat_parentid =  category["cat_parentid"]
                let name =  category["name"]
                let year =  category["year"]


                self.tableArray.append(cat_id ?? "unknnown")
                self.cartname.append(cat_name ?? "unknnown")
                self.parentid.append(cat_parentid ?? "unknnown")
                self.name.append(name ?? "unknnown")
                self.year.append(year ?? "unknnown")
            }
```

Tableview cell data load

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

        cell.cat_id.text = self.tableArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.cat_name.text = self.cartname[indexPath.row]// Some time Here I am getting out of range error
        cell.cat_parentid.text = self.parentid[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = self.name[indexPath.row]  // Here I am getting out of range error
        cell.year.text = self.year[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected with multiple arrays when using the tableView ,First from **OOP** point you need to create 1 model like

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let catID, catName, catParentid, year,name: String? 

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case catID = "cat_id"
        case catName = "cat_name"
        case catParentid = "cat_parentid"
        case year, name
    }
}
```

and use `Codable` to parse the json

```
var arr = [Root]()

do {  
  let content = json["content"] as! [[String:String]]
  let staData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:content,options:[]) 
  arr = try JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self, from:staData) 
} 
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

in numberOfRows

```
return arr.count
```

---

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
        let item = arr[indexPAth.row]
        cell.cat_id.text = item.catID
        cell.cat_name.text = item.catName
        cell.cat_parentid.text = item.catParentid
        cell.name.text = item.name  
        cell.year.text = item.year 
        return cell 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will recreate my JSON. @Sh_Khan

Comment: How to get values inside cell for row at index @Sh_Khan